# Base64 in C# and PL/SQL?

Tags: c#, string, plsql, base64

In PL/SQL how can I convert a string (long HTML string with new line and tags, etc) to Base64 that is easy to decrypt in C#?

In C# there are:

```
Convert.ToBase64String()
Convert.ToBase64CharArray()
BitConverter.ToString()
```

which one is compatible with PL/SQL

```
utl_encode.base64_encode();
```

?

I welcome any other suggestions :-)

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question. Why not make it an "answer" below?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean?

Comment: What @AdamHawkes means is that `utl_encode.base64_encode();` does Base64 encoding in PL/SQL. @Data-Base

Comment: Wait, ok, I got it! Now I see, it's not about the stored procedure, it's about the C# method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it :-)

PL/SQL

```
s1 varchar2(32767);
s2 varchar2(32767);

s2:= utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s1)));
s2:= utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(s1)));
```

are compatible with C#

```
public static string ToBase64(string str)
{
         return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
}

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

public static string FromBase64(string str)
{
         return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
}
```

hope you find it useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use this method:

```
Convert.ToBase64String()
```

It returns a Base64 encoded String based off an array of unsigned 8-bit integers (bytes).

As an alternate, you can use `Convert.ToBase64CharArray()`, but the output is a character array, which is a bit odd but may be useful in certain circumstances.

The method `BitConverter.ToString()` returns a String, but the bytes are represented in Hexadecimal, not Base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks, but which one gives me the same results as utl_encode.base64_encode(); in PL/SQL? i'm asking because right now I do not have access to my Oracle Database, cheers

Comment: It's a bit hard to say which is closest. `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE` has a RAW parameter and returns a RAW. That RAW must then be turned into a string (VARCHAR2) to match the output of `Convert.ToBase64String`.